# Condicional If dentro de map() com function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Olá!
Tenho uma linha de código assim:

```js
    if (searchQuery.length != 0) {
      return (
        <Row hidden>
          {searchQuery.map((res) => (
```

Neste trecho de código, estou tentando acrescentar um **if** logo após o **=> (** com as chaves "{ if...".

O que desejo fazer é: acrescentar um **if** para que somente se "*res.display*" estiver **true** (no Strapi, como um *booleano*), para dar continuidade no código. Dessa maneira, que não funciona (e diversas — 12 horas tentando — outras):

```js
{ if ({res.display /*como true*/}) { 
    //todo o trecho de código executável
}
```

Ele me devolve um erro de síntaxe, esperando que o "*res.display*" tenha um vírgula no lugar do ponto; talvez desejando que fosse um *parâmetro* (devido as chaves).

O projeto total é que tenho cards dentro do sítio e gostaria de ocultar as próprias que estiverem com **false** no **booleano** "*display*" que criei no *Strapi*. Sem a necessidade de excluí-las, para repô-las quando necessário; vi, também, que na versão ^3.2 do *Strapi*, há função de **publish/unpublish**, porém estou utilizando a 3.1.4, sendo assim, tentando atualizar os pacotes, quebrei totalmente o sistema.

***Edição:***

Tentei fazer como o amigo @Jason Rabelo ensinou e tive problemas, novamente.
Deixarei o trecho do código inteiro para que possa ser entendido melhor:

```js
/* components/ServiceList/index.js */
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Link from "next/link";
import LayerMoreInfo from "../../components/LayerMoreInformation";

import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardImg,
  CardText,
  CardTitle,
  CardHeader,
  CardFooter,
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  Jumbotron,
  Button,
  Carousel,
  CarouselItem,
  CarouselControl,
  CarouselIndicators,
  CarouselCaption,
  Spinner
} from "reactstrap";

const QUERY = gql`
  {
    services {
      id
      name
      description
      image {
        url
      }
      header
      display
    }
  }
`;

function ServiceList(props) {

  const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('Closed');
  
  const onEntering = () => setStatus('Opening...');
  
  const onEntered = () => setStatus('Opened');
  
  const onExiting = () => setStatus('Closing...');
  
  const onExited = () => setStatus('Closed');
  
  const toggle = () => setCollapse(!collapse);

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUERY);
  if (error) return "Error loading services";
  //If services are returned from the GraphQL query, run the filter query
  //and set equal to variable serviceSearch
  if (loading) return ( <Spinner style={{ width: '5rem', height: '5rem', textAlign: "center", alignContent: "center" }}  color="primary" /> );
  if (data.services && data.services.length) {
    //searchQuery
    const searchQuery = data.services.filter((query) =>
      query.name.toLowerCase().includes(props.search)
    );
    if (searchQuery.length != 0) {
      return (
        <Row>
          {searchQuery.filter((res) => /* isso sendo um teste, baseado na solução do Jason:  {if (res.display) { return ( */

            <Col sm="4" key={res.id}>
              <Card style={{ margin: "20px 0px 20px 0px", textAlign: "center" }} className="layerCard">

                <CardHeader tag="h4">{res.header}</CardHeader>

                <CardBody style={{ height: "150px" }}>
                  <CardTitle tag="h5">{res.name}</CardTitle>
                  <CardText>{res.description}</CardText>
                </CardBody>

                <CardImg
                  top={true}
                  style={{ height: "180px", textAlign: "center" }}
                  src={`${res.image[0].url}`}
                  className="img-responsive"
                />
                <LayerMoreInfo id={res.id} />
                
              </Card>
            </Col>
          ))}

          <style jsx global>
            {`
              a {
                color: white;
              }
              a:link {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
              }
              a:hover {
                color: white;
              }
              .card-columns {
                column-count: 3;
              }
            `}
          </style>
        </Row>
        //aqui a o fechamento do condicional if: );}}
      );
      } else {
      return <h1>No Services Found</h1>;
    }
  }

}

export default ServiceList;
```

Infelizmente, ele me respondeu com diversos erros em chaves e parêntesis fora deste "{if (res.display..."; incluindo no `else` do `if (searchQuery.length != 0)`

***Edição 2:***

Consegui resolver o problema, baseando em um pouco de observabilidade e a resposta do @Jason Rabelo.
A solução está entre as respostas, com minha resposta.

Comment: você tentou remover da chave ? if(res.display)

Comment: Sim, amigo. Não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia amigo,
as `callbacks functions` do javascript não precisa você faça uma estrutura `if` completa nesse tipo de situação, você pode fazer assim:

```
searchQuery.map((res) => res.display);
```

Lembrando que nesse caso a função `map`, vai retornar um `array` contendo apenas os resultados de display ou seja um array contendo todos os `true` ou `false`

se você quer filtar e trazer apenas todos os itens de um `array` onde o `display` seja `true`, então você deve usar a função `filter` dessa forma:

```
searchQuery.filter((res) => res.display);
```

se você achar melhor usar a estrutura completa de `if` você pode fazer essa seguinte forma:

```
searchQuery.filter((res) => {
   if (res.display) {
     return true;
   }
);
```

Coloquei apenas como exemplo para você, mas como a `variável` é uma `booleana`, então você não precisa comparar o valor, apenas retornar ele já é suficiente.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Jason, vou editar minha pergunta para acrescentar o trecho do código inteiro, para que você entenda melhor o problema. Tentei fazer como você explicou, mas tive mais dificuldade, apesar de parecer uma ótima solução.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, graças ao exemplo do @Jason e um pouco de observação no próprio código.
Percebi que havia um `return` logo acima, então simplesmente o "repeti" assim `{ if (res.display) { return (`

```js
    if (searchQuery.length != 0) {
      return (
        <Row>
          {searchQuery.map((res) => 
          { if (res.display) { return (
            <Col sm="4" key={res.id}>
```

Muito obrigado, @Jason Rabelo.